# How do I run multiple jobs with a given IJobConsumer within a single service instance?

Tags: masstransit

I want to be able to execute multiple jobs concurrently on a Job Consumer. At the moment if I run one service instance and try to execute 2 jobs concurrently, 1 job waits for the other to complete (i.e. waits for the single job slot to become available).

However if I run 2 instances by using dotnet run twice to create 2 separate processes I am able to get the desired behavior where both jobs run at the same time.

Is it possible to run 2 (or more) jobs at the same time for a given consumer inside a single process? My application requires the ability to run several jobs concurrently but I don't have the ability to deploy many instances of my application.

Checking the application log I see this line which I feel may have something to do with it:

```
[04:13:43 DBG] Concurrent Job Limit: 1
```

I tried changing the `SagaPartitionCount` to something other than 1 on `instance.ConfigureJobServiceEndpoints` to no avail. I can't seem to get the Concurrent Job Limit to change.

My configuration looks like this:

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddDelayedMessageScheduler();
    x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

    // registering the job consumer
    x.AddConsumer<DeploymentConsumer>(typeof(DeploymentConsumerDefinition));

    x.AddSagaRepository<JobSaga>()
        .EntityFrameworkRepository(r =>
        {
            r.ExistingDbContext<JobServiceSagaDbContext>();
            r.LockStatementProvider = new SqlServerLockStatementProvider();
        });
    // add other saga repositories here for JobTypeSaga and JobAttemptSaga here as well


    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        var rmq = configuration.GetSection("RabbitMq").Get<RabbitMq>();
        cfg.Host(rmq.Host, rmq.Port, rmq.VirtualHost, h =>
        {
            h.Username(rmq.Username);
            h.Password(rmq.Password);
        });

        cfg.UseDelayedMessageScheduler();

        var options = new ServiceInstanceOptions()
            .SetEndpointNameFormatter(context.GetService<IEndpointNameFormatter>() ?? KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter.Instance);

        cfg.ServiceInstance(options, instance =>
        {
            instance.ConfigureJobServiceEndpoints(js =>
            {
                js.SagaPartitionCount = 1;
                js.FinalizeCompleted = true;
                js.ConfigureSagaRepositories(context);
            });

            instance.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
        });
    });
}
```

Where `DeploymentConsumerDefinition` looks like

```
public class DeploymentConsumerDefinition : ConsumerDefinition<DeploymentConsumer>
{
    protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator,
        IConsumerConfigurator<DeploymentConsumer> consumerConfigurator)
    {
        consumerConfigurator.Options<JobOptions<DeploymentConsumer>>(options =>
        {
            options.SetJobTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20));
            options.SetConcurrentJobLimit(10);
            options.SetRetry(r =>
            {
                r.Ignore<InvalidOperationException>();
                r.Interval(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition should specify the job consumer message type, not the job consumer type:

```cs
public class DeploymentConsumerDefinition : ConsumerDefinition<DeploymentConsumer>
{
    protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator,
        IConsumerConfigurator<DeploymentConsumer> consumerConfigurator)
    {

                                                // MESSAGE TYPE NOT CONSUMER TYPE
        consumerConfigurator.Options<JobOptions<DeploymentCommand>>(options =>
        {
            options.SetJobTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20));
            options.SetConcurrentJobLimit(10);
            options.SetRetry(r =>
            {
                r.Ignore<InvalidOperationException>();
                r.Interval(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            });
        });
    }
}
```